# Crystal Report page height runtime setup

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I want to create a report for "Order print" and this report will be printed on a roll printer, this mean that the page height of the report depends on the number of rows which are created dynamically.

Width of the page is 8 c.m. and height should be based on number of rows in detail. Sometimes report print area is 5c.m. sometimes it is 20 c.m. or any other measurement.

I want to know how to configure the "Page Setup" to change the height of the crystal report dynamically.

Please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution can be useful:

- Set your header information in the `Report Header` section.
- Don't use `Page Header` section.
- Set your footer information in the `Report Footer` section.
- Don't use `Page Footer` section.
- Set margins of top and bottom of page to minimum and if it's possible set them to `0`.

With this solution you will have a report like this:

```
+------------------+    \ 
|  Header Section  |    | 
+------------------+    | Page 1
| Detail row 1     |    |
| Detail row 2     |    |
| Detail row 3     |    / ------
| Detail row 4     |    \
| Detail row 5     |    |
| Detail row 6     |    | Page 2
| Detail row 7     |    |
| Detail row 8     |    |
| Detail row 9     |    / ------
| Detail row 10    |    \
| Detail row 11    |    |
: Detail row ...   :
| Detail row last  |    | Last Page
+------------------+    |
|  Footer Section  |    |
+------------------+    /
```