# Crystal report start with blank space in every new pages including first

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have to take print of bill in roll printer.
My CR page size is 8cm x 12 cm.
When I print (direct to printer) Crystal report start with 7cm blank space in every new pages including first one.

Is there any solution to fix this issue ?

[Crystal Report page height runtime setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084801/crystal-report-page-height-runtime-setup/31087420#31087420)

as per this question and answer I have created Crystal report.

Please help to solve the issue.

[image: receiptPrint]

[image]
[image: design vew]

Comment: How much space your header is consuming

Comment: its around 7 cm, sorry in my question I had a mistake..every blank space is 7 cm

Comment: Have you suppressed the page header and page footer sections?

Comment: yes, I suppressed both blank sections

Comment: What about detail sections? how you made the fields to fit to section?

Comment: its only one row for all fields, to print items,rate,qty, price, etc. Size less than 1 c.m., Sorry I didnt get your second question

Comment: may you post a screen capture of the report? and maybe another one from the designer?

Comment: I uploaded screen shots and print snap shot. Preview showing as 2 pages , so that in output showing with blank space on each page

Comment: when I increased size to 8 x 27 (8 x 12 was old), blanks space shows only at the bottom of print

Comment: How is it displayed when you view it on screen.

Comment: view was perfect in crystal report viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by incrementing page height to 27 cm, then I suppressed blank space, now getting perfect print.. Thanks to all for yours support