# Malayalam Printing Issue from win forms application on dot matrix printer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports-8.5, dot-matrix

Iam working on a windows application to print Malayalam on billing.Used crystal report to print but its not stops after the last line finished printing.its rolling to a fixed height after printing. Is there any option to set the page height dynamically from crystal report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Report page height runtime setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084801/crystal-report-page-height-runtime-setup)

Comment: Thanks ....I got my problem solved....